# Is it possible to compute permutations of a sequence of bytes by using exactly one pseudo-random number?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, permutation, pseudo-random-permutation

Suppose I have a certain sequence of bytes, for example 0102F4829<sub>hex</sub>, and I can pick from a pseudo-random number generator exactly one number.
Is it possible, by using exactly one pseudo-random number each time, to generate all the permutations of the initial sequence of bytes following a uniform distribution?

Comment: Uniform? Generally, no. Indistinguishable from uniform? Sure, as long as the "number" is large enough. What's "a number" to you?

Comment: It is a 32 bytes pseudo-random integer and my sequence of bytes is 32 bytes long as well.

Comment: I am considering the constraint of using exactly one pseudo-random number since I am in a context where I cannot pick pseudo-random numbers until I am satisfied (e.g., until I have a certain number of different pseudo-random numbers). It means that I could not use something like the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm to compute permutations.

Comment: Could you share a reference or explain how to do it?

Comment: You can just stretch that value 32 byte value arbitrarily using any secure PRG. E.g. AES-256 in CTR mode.

Comment: I got your point.  If the number of possible pseudo-random numbers is less than the numbers of possible computations, I cannot obtain all of them.